# Create a vector with repeated values in DolphinDB

Tags: vector, dolphindb

Given a vector, for example

a = [1, 2, 3]

How do I expand the vector to a new one like [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ...] in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 1):

You can use function `take` to take n values iteratively and sequentially and generate a new one.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
take(a,9)
```

output

```
offset  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
0   1   2   3   1   2   3   1   2   3
```